# How can I define a route for search process in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, search

I have a problem about defining a route with respect to a **search** process in the controller part of **ASP.NET MVC**.

What I want to do is to get this **URL** which is defined below after I click a search button in the form.

```
Blog/Search?searchKeyword=banana
```

I created a sample form but I have no idea how to define the url in its action. How can I do that?

Here is the code related with a form code snippet which is shown below.

```
<form action="Blog/Search/" method="get">
     <input type="text" name="searchKeyword">
     <button type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Here is the search function which is defined in the controller part shown below.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Blog/Search/{searchKeyword}")]
public ActionResult BlogSearch(string search_string, int Sayfa = 1)
{
  var searchList = db.Blog.Include("Category").Where(
      x => x.Content.Contains(search_string)).OrderByDescending(x => x.BlogId).ToPagedList(Page, 5);
  return View(searchList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer shown below.

js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#searchButton").click(function () {
            var searchKeyword = $("#searchKeyword").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/BlogSearch/',
                data: {searchKeyword: searchKeyword},
                type: 'POST'
            });
        });
    })

</script>
```

BlogSearch Process

```
public ActionResult BlogSearch(string search_string, int Sayfa = 1)
        {
            var searchList = db.Blog.Include("Kategori").Where(
                      x => x.Icerik.Contains(search_string)).OrderByDescending(x => x.BlogId).ToPagedList(Sayfa, 5);
            return View(searchList);
        }
```